# Get model or 404 on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to use a function as get_by_id_or_404 on rails. For example, in my controller I use :

```
@destination = Destination.find_by_id(params[:id])
```

if the id isn't set or the destination not found, how can I ask Rails to redirect to a 404 page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

In production mode, Rails automatically rescues the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception by rendering the 404 error page.

Simply use the bang version of the finder that raises `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when no result is found.

```
@destination = Destination.find_by_id!(params[:id])
```

However, in your case there's no reason to use the `find_by` method. Simply fallback to `find`.

```
@destination = Destination.find(params[:id])
```

Answer (score 6):

This is from [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#dynamic-finders):

> You can specify an exclamation point (!) on the end of the dynamic finders to get them to raise an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error if they do not return any records, like Client.find_by_name!("Ryan")

When this happens, Rails will render the 404 page for you. Also, simply use `find` as a shortcut for `find_by_id`:

```
@destination = Destination.find!(params[:id])
```

Comment: No need for the exclamation mark! Check the [docs for `find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find), it will raise RecordNotFound if you pass it an id.

Comment: I guess you meant that find is a shortcut for find_by_id!

Answer (score 3):

I think in production, it will raise the error and display the 404 or 500.

Comment: Unless you change the finder method, that method won't generate any exception.